# Comparar una lista de coordenadas con otra y su radio

Tags: python, numpy

Buenas!

Veamos tengo una función que me genera una lista (*Lista A*) de coordenadas en ***numpy***.

> `[[1,1][1,6][3,5][5,7]]` <- (por ejemplo)

Y tengo por otro lado otra lista (*lista B*) con mas coordenadas (También en formato ***numpy***)

> `[[2,1][1,5][7,8][9,10][10,10][11,11]]`

Entonces mi objetivo es , pasandole la *lista A* y un radio (de 1 por ejemplo) compare con la *lista B* y me diga que puntos de la *lista A* se cruza con alguno de la *lista B*. en este caso pasándole radio 1 pues me diría

*lista A* `[[1,1][1,6]]` se cruza con lista `[[2,1][1,5]]`

he pensado hace una función que te genera el área de cada punto de la *lista A* con ese radio. y luego te haga un convexhull... pero no se si existirá una función mas rápida y optima, ya que mi lista tiene mas de 100.000 puntos.

El código que tengo es el siguiente (pero es la versión no optima)

```
def getRadius(cords,radio):
#   print cords[1:] lado derecho
#   print cords[:1] lado izquierdo 
    x = []
    y = []
    x.append(np.asscalar(cords[1:]) + radio/2)
    x.append(np.asscalar(cords[1:]) - radio/2)
    y.append(np.asscalar(cords[:1]) + radio/2)
    y.append(np.asscalar(cords[:1]) - radio/2)
    return(np.array(list(itertools.product(y, x))))

def getListNewCoords(listCoords,radio,Poids):
    newList = []
    for i in listCoords:
        newCoords = getRadius(i,radio)
        inHull = in_hull(Poids,newCoords)
        z = Poids[inHull]
        if not z:
            newList.append(i)
    return(newList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes calcular la distancia de cada punto de la primera lista (la llamaré `a`) con la distancia de todos los puntos de la segunda lista (la llamaré `b`). Si lo haces por cada punto de la primera lista lo puedes ir haciendo de forma iterativa (no sé como quieres el output). Un ejemplo podría ser:

```
import numpy as np

# array con 15 puntos
a = np.random.randint(1,10,(15,2))
# array con 10 puntos
b = np.random.randint(1,10,(10,2))

# Función que calcula la distancia de un 
# punto de en 'a' a todos los puntos de 'b'
def calcula_distancias(point, arr, radio=1):
    dist = np.sqrt((point[0] - arr[:,0])**2 + (point[1] - arr[:,1])**2)
    indexes = dist <= radio
    return arr[indexes], indexes

for punto in a:
    print(punto, calcula_distancias(punto, b, radio=3)) # ajusta el radio
```

La función te devuelve los puntos de `b` que están a la misma distancia o menos de `radio`. Podrías hacerlo de una sin necesidad del `for` construyendo un array de distancias que tuviera las dimensiones de `(len(a), len(b))` y a partir del mismo crear un array de booleanos con los que estuvieran por debajo de `radio` pero eso lo dejo como deberes al que quiera.

Comment: Hola , muchas gracias, parece que funciona esta solución , lo que en radio se refiere es expresado en distancia en metros no?

Comment: Pues depende de cómo metas los valores de los puntos que estés usando, para el radio deberías usar las mismas unidades. El ejemplo no tiene en cuenta unidades.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como lo cuentas creo que te te iría bien alguna técnica de *"clusterización"* (eg: k-means). Lo que no te aconsejo cuando tienes gran cantidad de puntos que hagas una comparación `O(n^2)` como la solución que propones o la que propone @kikocorreoso.

La estrategia que yo seguiría dividir la listas de puntos de algún modo para limitar la cantidad de puntos a comparar (*"clustering"*). Por ejemplo, podemos calcular la media de todos los puntos de una lista y dividirla en cuatro listas. Para hacer la comparación, primero comparamos con la media calculada para saber con cuál de los 4 clústers tenemos que comparar. Un código para darte una idea:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

# array con 1500 puntos
a = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (1500, 2))
# array con 1000 puntos
b = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (1000, 2))

m = b.mean(0)

radius = 1

cluster = [
    b[np.logical_and(b[:,0] <= m[0]+radius, b[:,1] <= m[1]+radius)],
    b[np.logical_and(b[:,0] >  m[0]-radius, b[:,1] <= m[1]+radius)],
    b[np.logical_and(b[:,0] <= m[0]+radius, b[:,1] >  m[1]-radius)],
    b[np.logical_and(b[:,0] >  m[0]-radius, b[:,1] >  m[1]-radius)],
]

def getCluster(p):
    k  = 0 if p[0] <= m[0] else 2
    k += 0 if p[1] <= m[1] else 1
    return cluster[k]

def dist(x,y):
    return sqrt((x[0]-y[0])**2 + (x[1]-y[1])**2)

res = [ (x,y) for x in a for y in getCluster(x)
         if dist(x,y) <= radius ]

def unzip(tuples): return list(zip(*tuples))


from pprint import pprint
pprint(unzip(res))
```

Hemos reducido las comparaciones a realizar en 1/4. Podemos seguir aplicando la misma estrategia volviendo a dividir cada clúster en cuatro hasta llegar a un tamaño de clúster asumible (~1000 elementos). Si tenemos máquina con varios procesadores, podemos incluso plantearnos paralelizar el proceso encargando a cada procesador un clúster (similar a lo que haría Apache Spark).

De todos modos, casi seguro que puedan serte de ayuda alguna herramienta de clustering como [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/cluster.html) y [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) (no las conozco mucho).